# MacOs CGDisplayIsActive() always fails for daemon if it fails once

Tags: macos, daemon, quartz-graphics

I have a project that needs a daemon process to be able to access the Mac display at boot up time. I have discovered that all the MacOs CGDisplay... access routines fail when the daemon first comes up. If I sleep for a while then they work fine.

I thought I could try something like this:

```
while (!CGDisplayIsActive(CGMainDisplayID())) {

    if ( ++errCnt == 20 ) {
        trace(0,"CGDisplayIsActive never went true\n");
        return -1;
    }
    trace(0,"display not active on count errCnt %d\n", errCnt);
    sleep(5);
};
```

but once the CGDisplayIsActive routine fails, it seems never to return success.

This works but surely there's a better way:

```
   if (!CGDisplayIsActive(CGMainDisplayID())) {
    trace(0,"CGDisplayIsActive not true, wait a bit and then let launchd start again\n");
    sleep(5); 
    exit(0);
   }
```

Is there some way to wait for the display service to become active?

TFYS